# ajax jquery , query not getting called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Made something simple like a follow system using ajax jquery on my own, thats the function:

```
function follow(name){  
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "../include/follow.inc.php", 
            data: "name",
            cache: false, 
        }); 
    }
```

and that is the button which calls that function

`<button onClick="follow('.$nome.');"></button>`

This is how i call the button.

```
$my_name = $_SESSION['account_name']; 
$user = $_POST['name'];

if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $query = "INSERT INTO followed (follower, followed) VALUES ('$my_name', '$user')";
    $result = $database->query($query); 
}
```

At the end of the day, it all looks alright until the query is not getting called.
basically what it does is, gets the name (of the user you wish to follow) , it adds the name in follow(name) and proceeds adding it in a query (this is where it fails).

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Check the syntax of `data: "name",` HINT its wrong

Comment: Maybe try `data: {name: name},`

Comment: Some basic debuuging would tell you that `isset($_POST['name'])` is false and you would work backwards to find out why

Comment: could the problem be because im passing a string as a parameter to a function onclick event jquery? i tried debugging, the event is not getting called at all

Comment: If event not working check browser dev tools console for errors. As for the string you have to send key/value pairs....all you were sending is the value part so there is no key for $_POST plus it is a hard coded string value not related to what is passed into function

Answer (score 0):

your codes has two problem

1 - you create your variable $name before checking that the name exists or not and in debugging mode you see the notice of php

2 - your codes is open to XSS or SQL Injection Attacks as [riggsfolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) said in comments

and for your problem: try this and let us known the result

---

php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $my_name = $_SESSION['account_name']; 
    $user = $_POST['name'];
    $result = $database->query("INSERT INTO followed (follower, followed) VALUES ('" . $my_name . "', '" . $user . "')"); 
    if($result){
        echo('ok');
    }else{
        echo('error');
    }
}
```

---

function:

```
function follow(n){  
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../include/follow.inc.php',
        data: { name: n },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert('Error in AJAX request !');
        }
    }); 
}
```

---

dont forget to use a xss cleaning function for getting your data from clients in methods

```
$user = your_any_xss_clean_function($_POST['name']);
```